# How to use mTLS without using istio ingress and using azure app gateway ingress?

Tags: aks, istio

We have our application running in aks cluster and using cert-manager helm chart in separate namespace for lets encrypt certificate generation. argocd namespace is for handling deployments.

We need to enable mTLS, does that required istio to be labelled on argocd,cert-manager namespaces also?

And, we already have azure appgateway ingress to route traffic to the deployments running in our namespace, so didn’t enabled istio ingress.

Once I enabled strict option at global level, the routing is not working from azure app gateway ingress to our application.

```
kubectl apply -n istio-system -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
EOF
```

And getting 502 bad gateway.

If I remove above peerauthentication or change that to PERMISSIVE.
Then it is able to access page without 502 error.

What to do for this to implement strict mode but without istio ingress.

```
kubectl edit peerauthentication -n istio-system
peerauthentication.security.istio.io/default edited
```